# Is there any way to see / reveal Akali in her Twilight Shroud?

Tags: league-of-legends

I laned against an Akali recently who used her Twilight Shroud very effectively to keep me from targeting her.  Is there any way to reveal or see her if she's not attacking?

Comment: [Oracle's Elixir](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle%27s_Elixir)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Twilight Shroud is just like any other form of stealth. This means, among other things:

- Area of Effect abilities and attacks will still affect her. Akali's stealth is very limited in location -- if she's stealthed, you have a pretty good idea of where she is.
- Any stealth revealing item, like Vision Ward or Oracle's Alteration means you won't lose track of the ninja (though she will retain her armor / MR bonus as long as she's in the cloud. Sweeping Lens will also warn of her location, but not reveal her.
- Use champion abilities (where applicable) to reveal her. Lee Sin's Q or E, Nidalee's Traps, and Kog'maw's Living Artillery all reveal stealthed units -- and, again, you know where Akali is (relatively). If you are (or have one of these champions on your team) make sure that they're using their anti-stealth abilities to reveal her.

Comment: +1 for being far more thorough than me. I never play Corki, so I didn't think about his ability. I'm smacking myself for not thinking of Nidalee or Kog's abilities.

Comment: Lee Sin slamming down Tempest in the middle will reveal the entire area; always fun :P

Answer (score 3):

Oracle and Vision wards. But there are some spells that might not see her but could attack her or draw her out of stealth.

- Shen's Taunt can draw Akali out of her shroud.
- Any one with skill shots, e.g. Ezreal, Caitlyn, Anivia, Dr. Mundo... These attacks could either kill Akali or make her need to leave her shroud cause she might die inside.
- Katarina's ult can focus invisible champs so ulting near the shroud would kit Akali.
- It's mentioned above that Corki's Phosphorus Bombs (his Q) can reveal Akali, but that was changed in a previous patch, it no longer reveals stealth.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Vision Ward (150 gold, 4 minute duration ward) or Oracle's Elixer (400 gold, permanent till your death). These should reveal her in her shroud, unless they have changed it in a recent patch.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already mentioned ways to reveal Akali, you can also use Shen's taunt ability to bring her out of stealth. Simply rush through her little area of stealthiness and she will have to auto attack you which will cause her to unstealth.